# Is there a mysql function that will compare two fields in a table?

Tags: mysql

```
item name|quantity|minimum level|
---------------------------------
bearing  |  3     |     5       |
screw    |  5     |     10      |
bolt     |  20    |     20      |
```

It is not a date but a int type.I only want to display the item name that is below minimum level. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: MySQL != JavaScript, Why JS tag

Comment: How is this related to Javascript?

Comment: I believe you need to first define the `minimum level` and use it in your `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely it can't just be as simple as

```
SELECT item_name 
FROM Items
WHERE quantity < minimum_level;
```

Comment: example is so simple..sorry i am no good with research..thank you StuartLC